# Before Truncateonly , rebuild vs reoganize

Tags: sql-server

I have a huge space unused = 500 GB.

I am planning to use truncateonly.

To minimize the unused space , should I use rebuild or reoganize before truncateonly ?

Answer (score 0):

I would truncate first and shrink your DB down, and then re-build the indexes. I have found that the DB always grows once you rebuild indexes, so if you shrink the database after the indexes have been re-built, I think they will need rebuilding again.